# Conditional where clause using non-NULL parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to write a script with a conditional where clause. pretty much like this. is this do-able?
this is a stored procedure which will be called by a vb.net application and the value of @ModeType will determine the parameters to be used in the where clause. i will pass dbnull values to the unused parameters where necessary.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[newNBOCAP_DATA_UPDATE]
@StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime,
@ReferralID integer,
@ModeType varchar (50)

select * from tableA
where
case
when @ModeType = 'proforma' and @ReferralID IS NOT NULL
then referral = @ReferralID
when @ModeType = 'download' and ISDATE(@StartDate) = 1 and ISDATE(@EndDate) = 1
then startdate = @StartDate and enddate = @EndDate
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People always seem to rush to try to use `CASE` when in fact all they need is basic boolean logic:

```
select * from tableA
where
(@ModeType = 'proforma' and @ReferralID IS NOT NULL and referral =@ReferralID) or
(@ModeType = 'download' and ISDATE(@StartDate) = 1 and ISDATE(@EndDate) = 1 and
    startdate = @StartDate and enddate = @EndDate)
```

Although, of course, `referral =@ReferralID` can never be true if `@ReferralID` *is* NULL, unless `ANSI_NULLS` is off which is [not recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx). Also, variables declared as `datetime` can only be valid dates or `NULL`, so we can probably simplify further to:

```
select * from tableA
where
(@ModeType = 'proforma' and referral =@ReferralID) or
(@ModeType = 'download' and startdate = @StartDate and enddate = @EndDate)
```

Comment: Performance may well be sub optimal though. The `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` approach doesn't work on 2005 and simply splitting into two different queries may well be best to take advantage of any useful indexes.